# Cocos2d html5 cannot set property src of null

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5

Getting the subject error when going through: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/symbols/cc.html

Note that I am using the 2.1.2 beta release, so I know there will be differences in the tutorial. Here's the code i have so far:

```
(function() {
  var AppLayer = cc.LayerColor.extend({
    init: function() {
      this._super(new cc.Color4B(0, 0, 0, 255));
      var size = cc.Director.getInstance().getWinSize();
      this._jetSprite = new JetSprite();
      this.setTouchEnabled(true);
      this.setKeyboardEnabled(true);
      this.setPosition(new cc.Point(0, 0));

      this.addChild(this._jetSprite);
      this._jetSprite.setPosition(new cc.Point(size.width / 2, size.height / 2));
      this._jetSprite.scheduleUpdate();
      this.schedule(this.update);
      return true;
    },
    _jetSprite: null,
    onEnter: function() {
      this._super();
    },
    onKeyDown: function(e) {
      this._jetSprite.handleKey(e);
    },
    onKeyUp: function() {

    },
    onTouchesEnded: function(pTouch, pEvent) {
      this._jetSprite.handleTouch(pTouch[0].getLocation());
    },
    onTouchesMoved: function(pTouch, pEvent) {
      this._jetSprite.handleTouchMove(pTouch[0].getLocation());
    },
    update: function(dt) {

    }
  });


  window.AppScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter: function() {
      this._super();
      var layer = new AppLayer();
      layer.init();
      this.addChild(layer);
    }
  });
})();

var JetSprite = cc.Sprite.extend({
  _currentRotation:0,
  ctor: function() {
    this.initWithFile("images/jet.png");
  },
  handleKey: function(e) {
    if(e == cc.KEY.left) {
      this._currentRotation--;
    }
    else if(e == cc.KEY.right) {
      this._currentRotation++;
    }

    if(this._currentRotation < 0) {
      this._currentRotation = 360;
    }
    if(this._currentRotation > 360) {
      this._currentRotation = 0;
    }
  },
  handleTouch: function(touchLocation) {
    if(touchLocation.x < 300) {
      this._currentRotation = 0;
    }
    else {
      this._currentRotation = 180;
    }
  },
  handleTouchMove: function(touchLocation) {
    var angle = Math.atan2(touchLocation.x - 300, touchLocation.y - 300);

    angle = angle * (180/Math.PI);
    this._currentRotation = angle;
  },
  update: function(dt) {
    this.setRotation(this._currentRotation);
  }
});
```

Here's the error in more detail:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null CCSprite.js:2209
cc.SpriteWebGL.cc.Node.extend.initWithTexture CCSprite.js:2209
(anonymous function) CCSprite.js:2161
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the tutorial i was following was missing a line. The ctor function requires a this._super() so everything gets initialized correctly.

```
var JetSprite = cc.Sprite.extend({
  _currentRotation:0,
  ctor: function() {
    this._super();
    this.initWithFile("images/jet.png");
  },
```